# why do the values of array change?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Consider the code below in VB :

```
    Dim speed() As Integer = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim speed2() As Integer
    speed2 = speed

    For i = 0 To UBound(speed2)
        speed2(i) *= 2
    Next

    Dim str As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(speed)
        str &= speed(i)
    Next

    For i = 0 To UBound(speed2)
        str &= speed2(i)
    Next
 Console.WriteLine(str)
```

For this code the answer should be :
              12342468

but what really appears is :
              24682468

Does anyone know what's wrong with the code or why the array "speed" is changing its values  ?

Comment: The problem with .NET is that once you have a reference to an array, you cannot prevent others from changing your array. So in general always make copies of arrays before returning them from methods and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array `speed` changes its values because an array is a reference type.
Assigning an array to another array like you do in the line

```
 speed2 = speed
```

makes the array `speed2` reference the same memory locations where the values of `speed` are kept.
Thus, when you execute your calculation, the assignment affects the same memory locations used by `speed`

Comment: which means that they will always have the same values !!! thanks a lot, that explained everything to me

Answer (score 1):

doing this should fix it

```
    Dim speed() As Integer = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim speed2() As Integer
    ReDim speed2(speed.GetUpperBound(0))
    Array.Copy(speed, 0, speed2, 0, speed.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I was going to use a for loop to assign the values one by one but this way is much better